# JQuery Form Validation 'Not Defined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am having some issues with JavaScript check my form for completion before submission.  Here is my form code:

```
<form class="myform" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="https://Autorespondercode.com" method="POST">

<div class="front-name"><input class="form-name" id="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" name="inf_field_FirstName" placeholder="First Name" /></div>


<div class="front-email"><input class="form-email" id="inf_field_Email" type="text" name="inf_field_Email" placeholder="Email" /></div>


<input style="background-color: #fc8f12;" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />


</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm() { 
    var a=document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_FirstName"].value; 
    var b=document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Email"].value; 
    if (a==null || a=="" || a=="First Name")
    {   alert("Please enter your First Name!");   
    return false;   }     
    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;    
    if (document.myform.inf_field_Email.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1)  
    {           alert("Please enter a valid email address.");               
    return false;    } }
```

Appreciate any help/tips.

Comment: And... what is your problem that you encounter? Have you checked the console for errors thrown?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your script with:

```
    function validateForm() {
        var a = document.getElementById('inf_field_FirstName').value;
        var b = document.getElementById('inf_field_Email').value;
        if (a == null || a == "" || a == "First Name") {
            alert("Please enter your First Name!");
            return false;
        }
        var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        if (document.getElementById('inf_field_Email').value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
            alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Browser is not able to get value with:

```
  var a=document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_FirstName"].value; 
  var b=document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Email"].value;
```

Comment: Vicky, I think I am in love with you.  I've been driving my head against a wall for hours trying to fix that thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like, You have not mentioned the form name `myform` in your `form tag`,

```
   <form name="myform" class="myform" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="https://Autorespondercode.com" method="POST">
```